# How to solve moveit planning scene's PR2 robot position inconsistency?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example, I add a table and a cup before PR2.

This is the picture of planning scene:

[image: image description]

This is the picture that show PR2 robot model.

[image: image description]

It can easily found that two PR2 in different position.

Is it normal? Why?

If not, how to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182407/how-to-solve-moveit-planning-scene%27s-pr2-robot-position-inconsistency?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure that the fixed frame in RVIZ (under global options) is set to the same frame as the root of the planning scene. Currently, you have it set to "base_link" -- if using the default settings for the PR2, you need to set it to "odom_combined"

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2014-07-02**:
Why set to odom_combined is important? How to understand and learn it well? Thank you~

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-07-02**:
If odom_combined is the frame that the planning scene is referenced to (depends on what the root of  your tree is based on the SRDF/URDF), then that happens to be where the plugin puts everything properly. Really, the plugin *should* transform to other frames, but it currently does not do that.